# unable to echo custom title if page

Tags: php

i have a posttype to which i have a page templates assigned using plugin custom posttype page template, so that my posts having img attachments in the posttype are displayed using a particular template. In my header.php i have code

```
if ( is_page_template ( 'page-book.php' ) )
                { $currenturl=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                  $booktitle = str_replace("http://mybooks.com/books/", "", $currenturl);
                  $booktitle = str_replace("-", " ", $booktitle);
                  $booktitle = strtoupper($booktitle);
                  echo $booktitle;
                }
```

but it echoes the url of the post in the title instead of the custom echo

how do i get it to echo the custom title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `$currenturl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` of your code only return string that is part of the `URL`.

For example, the given url `http://mybooks.com/books/title` it return `/books/title` and when you try to replace it with an empty string nothing is replace because `str_replace` function doesn't find a match.

For you to get the trailing part of the url, you can use `basename`

For example

```
echo basename($currenturl);
```

It will return the last part of the url and that is

`title`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me. Try wit these solutions:

Solution 1:

```
$currenturl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$booktitle = str_replace("http://mybooks.com/books/", "", $currenturl);
$booktitle = str_replace("-", " ", $booktitle);
$booktitle = strtoupper($booktitle);
echo $booktitle;
```

or try debugging it with something like this:

Solution 2:

```
$currenturl = "http://mybooks.com/books/this-is-the-book-title";
$booktitle = str_replace("http://mybooks.com/books/", "", $currenturl);
$booktitle = str_replace("-", " ", $booktitle);
$booktitle = strtoupper($booktitle);
echo $booktitle;
```